# adding two values using react native and display the result

Tags: react-native

I'm developing simple calculator using react native, just for addition of two numbers. How can I store values to variable and display them using `TextInput`? And how to add those variables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
             <TextInput />
             <TextInput />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each `TextInput` you should save them to your state:

```
class Calc extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { f1: null, f2: null, result: null };
    }

    render() {
        const result = f1 && f2 ? f1 + f2 : null;
        return (
            <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({f1: parseInt(text)})}/>
            <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({f2: parseInt(text)})}/>

            { result ? <Text>{result}</Text> : null }
        );
    }
}
```

The important thing is the `onChangeText` that sets the state every time it changes. Also, you can use `keyboardType='numeric'` to show the numeric keyboard.

Comment: thank you, but at the closing of first textInput i am getting error. like " Adjecent jsx elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag"

Comment: in the above code i am getting, cant find variable:result, how can i fix that??

Answer (score 1):

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,StyleSheet,Text,TextInput,View,Button, } from 'react-native';
export default class logintut extends Component{


  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={ f1: '',f2: '',result: '' };   
    }
    render() {     
      var f1 = this.state.f1;
      var f2 = this.state.f2 ;
          const result = f1 && f2 ?  f2 + f1 : null; 

        return (  

           <View>                        
                 <TextInput keyboardType ='numeric' onChangeText= {(text) => this.setState({f1:parseInt(text)})} />

                 <TextInput keyboardType ='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({f2: parseInt(text)})} />

                 { result ? <Text>{ result }</Text> : null }
           </View>
        );
      }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('logintut', () => logintut);
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding two numbers we need to parse the string from **TextInput** to int using parseInt(text) function then add them on click of a button to display the result.

```
    <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({input1: parseInt(text)})}>
    <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({input2: parseInt(text)})}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
          this.setState({result: this.state.input1 && this.state.input2 ? this.state.input1 + this.state.input2 : null})}}>

// and for displaying result:
     <Text >{ this.state.result ? 'Result= '+ this.state.result : null}</Text>
```

I've created a sample project for addition using react native and native base libraries on github.
kindly refer: https://github.com/jayad-aadrit/react_native_appcenter

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is because the render function should only return one element, not several. So the easiest is just to wrap them in a View.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
             <TextInput />
             <TextInput />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Aside from that, from a quick overview I think you have have some other errors in the code, but I guess you'll work them out.

Comment: i just copied and ran the same code which has given by Eldelshell. you can see below that code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.8/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.8/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        class Calculator extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    number1 : 0,
                    number2 : 0,
                    result : 0
                }
            }

            doAction = () => {
                this.setState({result : parseInt(this.state.number1) + parseInt(this.state.number2) }); 
            }



            render(){
                return(
                <div>   
                <input type='number' onChange={(event)=>this.setState({number1:event.target.value})}/>
                <input type='number' onChange={(event)=>this.setState({number2:event.target.value})}/>
                <input type="button" onClick={this.doAction} value="Add"/>
                <input type='text' value={this.state.result} readonly/>
                </div>

                )
            }           
        }
    React.render(
        <Calculator/>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )       
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Button,
  Checkbox,
  WebView,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';



 class AwesomeProject extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { f1: null, f2: null, result: null };
    }


  

    render() {
     
      
       
        return (
          <View>
       
           
            <TextInput keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({f1: parseInt(text)})} />

            <TextInput keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({f2: parseInt(text)})} />


            </View>
        );
    }
}



AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  Button,
 
} from 'react-native';



 class AwesomeProject extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { f1: null, f2: null, result: null };
    }


  

    render() {
     
      
       
        return (
          <View>
           var result = f1 && f2 ? f1 + f2 : null;
           
            <TextInput keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({f1: parseInt(text)})} />

            <TextInput keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({f2: parseInt(text)})} />


              { result ? <Text>{ }</Text> : null }

            </View>
        );
    }
}



AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```